# Ejecutar una función de una vista desde otra vista

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, vue.js

estoy hace varios días tratando de resolver la siguiente situación y se me está haciendo complicado.

Por favor si me pueden brindar una mano estaré sumamente agradecido.

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 6.0 y Vue.js aunque busco una solución con cualquier lenguaje, javascript, ajax etc.

En el frontend tengo un usuario que se le bloquea la pantalla luego de ingresar unos datos:

```
 <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="validarCodigo">
              <!-- Heading -->
              <h3 class="dark-grey-text text-center mt-4">
                <strong>Validador Instagram:</strong>
                {{-- <label for="">VALOR: {{$usuario->id}}</label> --}}
              </h3>
              <hr>

              <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" :value="usuario_id='{{$usuario->id}}'" hidden>
              <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input v-model="email" type="email" id="form2" class="form-control">
                <label for="form2">Correo Electrónico</label>
              </div>
              <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input v-model="celular" type="text" id="form3" class="form-control">

                <label for="form4">CÓDIGO RECIBIDO</label>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-indigo">Validar</button>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Form -->

          </div>
            <div id="ocultaEstado" class="cargando" style="display:none;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" disabled>
                  <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  Espere aprobación por favor.
                </button>
```

Desde un perfil administrador un usuario admin aprueba esta solicitud

```
<td>
  <a href="/cambiarEstado/1/{{$usuario->id}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Aprobado</a>
  <a href="/cambiarEstado/2/{{$usuario->id}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Desaprobado</a>
</td>
```

En este mismo momento necesito redirigir al usuario a otra pantalla que diga que fue validado.

El controlador tiene lo siguiente:

```
public function cambiarEstado($estado, $id){
        Acceso::where('id', $id)->update(['estado' => $estado]);

    }
```

El problema es que no sé como trabajar en tiempo real esta situación. Utilice pushjs pero no lo logro activar en tiempo real, no sé como enviar esta aprobación de una vista a otra y desde controlador a otra vista tampoco me funciona.

Probé websocket y no me termina de funcionar debido a que no logro llegar hasta la vista del usuario. Alguien por favor que me pueda brindar una idea.

Comment: Puedes utilizar Pusher, la documentación de Laravel para broadcasting y la propia documentación de pusher te pueden ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado usar sockets? esto te puede ayudar a mantener una comunicación abierta con el servidor, para que cuando se apruebe el usuario este te indique la respuesta a la vista del usuario.

O si no tendrías que ejecutar un hilo que este haciendo llamadas constantes al servidor para validar si el usuario ya fue aprobado por el administrador